# 別シートを行検索して値を埋めたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

シート１に

```
key
1
2
3
2
1
```

とキーがかいてあって

シート２に

```
key val
1   abc
2   xyz
```

という感じでキーとうめたい文字列がかかれてるとして

シート１の２列目にシート２のキーに対応する文字列を入れたいです

LOOKUPメソッドを使えばできるみたいなんですが
`=LOOKUP(A2,'シート2'!A:A, 'シート2'!B:B)`
という計算式で２列目うめたところ

```
key val
1   abc
2   xyz
3   xyz
2   xyz
1   abc
```

となぜか key=3 の存在しない値までうまってしまいます

存在しない値は空白のままにしたいのですが可能でしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。`回答ありがとうございます。VLOOKUPもしらべたんですが検索範囲にB列も含めないと使えないみたいで、たまたまキーとバリュー文字列が一致してしまうケースがあったので断念しました。。。`のご返事について、`たまたまキーとバリュー文字列が一致してしまうケース`の意味が分かりませんでした。詳しくお教えいただけないでしょうか。また、投稿した回答はお役に立てなかったようですので削除させていただきます。申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: VLOOKUP(A4, A:A, 2, FALSE) とすると２列目を取り出そうとすると範囲外になってしまい VLOOKUP(A4, A:B, 2, FALSE) だとたとえばシート２のB列に３っていう値があるとマッチしてしまうんじゃないかと思ってるんですがそういうわけではないんでしょうか。今試せないので間違っていたらすみません。帰ってきたら試してみたいと思っています

Comment: 申し訳ありません。試したところ最初の回答でうまくいくようです。検索範囲という引数だったのでってっきり範囲全体を検索するかと思ったんですがドキュメントを読むと`「範囲の【先頭列】で検索キーとして指定したキーを検索します。」とありました。失礼しました。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。解決したようで安心しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlookupを使えばうまくいくと思います。※こちらの環境ではうまくいきました。

```
=vlookup(A2, 'シート2'!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

コードの重複が気になりますが、見つからなかったときに特定の文字列(今回はNG)とする場合は以下のように書けばよいです。

```
=if(isna(vlookup(A2, 'シート2'!A:B, 2, FALSE)), "NG", vlookup(A2, 'シート2'!A:B, 2, FALSE))
```

---

以下追記です。
`iferror`を使うともっと簡潔に書けました。

```
=iferror(vlookup(A2, 'シート2'!A:B, 2, FALSE), "NG")
```

`filter`を使った別解です。

```
=iferror(index(filter('シート2'!B:B,'シート2'!A:A=A2),1), "NG")
```

簡単に説明すると、'シート2'!A:Aの範囲でA2と同じ値を検索し、見つかった行のB列の値を返します。
今回の質問では使う必要はありませんが、検索する列と値を返す列が連続していない場合にはこの方法が有効だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。VLOOKUPでうまくいきました